# Get Productlist from order in success.phtml

Tags: orders

I try to get all the products from an order in the success.phtml
This is what I try so far:

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$_items = $order->getAllItems();
echo count($_items);
foreach($_items as $_item) {
```

`$order->getAllItems();` gives me a empty Array.

What is the right way to get the products from the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the function `getLastRealOrderId` will return the order increment id, in the default case 100000002 or similar. This is the number that is shown to the user as order id. But the load you are calling requires the actual entity_id of the order.

If you update the order load to use `loadByIncrementId` then this will really load the order you are looking for.

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$_items = $order->getAllItems();
echo count($_items);
```

Comment: Another thing to note is that $_items will be list of order items not products. If you need product details, you will have to fetch product from order item.

Comment: thanks that works. I get all data I need, for example the sku: `$_item->getProduct()->getData("sku")`. Only thing I didn't find yet is the quantity of the orderitem. `$_item->getQty()` returns nothing.

Comment: @myself: `$_item->getQtyToInvoice()`

Comment: try one of `getQtyBackordered` `getQtyOrdered` `getQtyCanceled` `getQtyInvoiced` `getQtyRefunded` `getQtyShipped` depending on what you need to show. They can be found against `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`